# How can I add static route?

Tags: macos, network

How can I add a static route "forever", that means without retyping `add route` in Terminal each time I'm using VPN? I found [this solution](http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/) for 10.6, but what if there is a nicer one for 10.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Lingon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12) to script this as a system startup - you can always use launchd to load or unload the job from the command line (or delete the route).

You don't *need* Lingon, it just makes it so much more friendly to assemble a plist that launchd likes to run.

Comment: It appears that [just adding a route script isn't enough](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37139/setting-a-static-route-every-boot-with-launchd-plist-is-failing) and some smarts on the timing of the command is needed for route to work reliably as a LaunchDaemon.