# Route all traffic to a particular domain/subdomain without VPN

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I'm using OpenVPN through Viscosity.

Is it possible to set it up in such a way that all traffic would go through the VPN, ***except*** traffic to a domain I'd specify (and all its subdomains, etc.)?

So only that one domain I'd specify would ***not*** use the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a static route to addresses you want, specifying the first hop in the chain, which can be an IP address or network device.

Here is a related question that involves establishing the static route at boot time.

[Setting a static route every boot with launchd / plist is failing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37139/setting-a-static-route-every-boot-with-launchd-plist-is-failing?lq=1)